# Keep getting Error on phpmyadmin when trying to add database or drop database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

Installed xampp on my mac but it did not run. It kept telling me that I needed to update MYSql so i did. Afterwards everything ran smoothly I was able to go to the phpmyadmin page. But now i cannot add a database or drop one. This message keeps popping up. Any one have any ideas?

[image]

New Error:
[image]

Comment: did you change the password or edit anything in the xampp settings

Comment: no i have not done anything besides updating MySql because it kept giving me an error when i first downloaded to update it after that i just re-downloaded xampp and this is what is happening now. and also when i click on an existing database it just keeps on loading and does noting else. @HashSu

Comment: did you build or run the settings file ? just checking... something like xamp_setting.bat

Comment: I ran everything. Just opened the DMG file and ran everything @HashSU

Comment: can u login to mysql manually in xampp? is it running in the xampp window?

Comment: @HashSu where exactly do I login and btw i refreshed the page do u think this has something to do with it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95371/discussion-between-hashsu-and-nbera).